# How to boot Ubuntu after removing Windows on UEFI system

Tags: boot, uefi, grub-efi

After previously dualbooting Ubuntu 14.04 lts with Windows 8.1, I finally bid my farewells to windows and wanted to make a complete switch to linux. I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 as there frame rate issues with 14.04 on my Toshiba Satellite. I then went to clear my hard drive to allow linux to properly take over. After the install completed I rebooted my laptop and discovered that it would not boot into either Ubuntu or Grub. There was a black screen saying Reboot or Insert Media. The only way I can boot now is with a USB. Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Access the UEFI screen while booting the system(by pressing the particular key).Then choose ubuntu there.

Comment: I have tried that countless times and it just doesn't work.

Comment: What are the options in your uefi screen?

Comment: All I can do is change secure boot and UEFI. I do have a Legacy option but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UEFI Secure Boot needs to be disabled in the system firmware.

You need to delete the entire partition table on the disk to be able to set up new GPT partitioning.You can use gparted from the live session

First if you are going to boot using EFI you must create with gparted a FAT formatted EFI System Partition (type EF00 ) as the first partition, around 500 Mb. This partition will contain your bootloader.

Second, you must create additional partitions for /, /home, swap and all it deems necessary.

After applying the changes, you should restart to begin the installation, choosing manual partitioning to select partitions.

The EFI System partition will also be mounted as /boot/efi, you do not need to tell the installer to mount this partition.